# Тест на случайность Кнута (критерий сериальной корреляции)

Tags: c, тестирование

Добрый день! Мне нужно реализовать один из тестов Кнута. Выбрала критерий сериальной корреляции. Во втором томе Кнута дается формула

[image: формула]

Я пытаюсь по ней вычислить этот коэффициент корреляции и он у меня получается при N=50 равный 1,04. Но он не может быть, по модулю, больше единицы!... Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться...

---

Кусочек кода:

```
const int M=N;
unsigned int null_num, first_num, numerator_n, numerator_2, denominator_n, denominator_2;
long double C;
null_num = (a*x+c)%4294967296;
numerator_n=0;
numerator_2 = null_num;
denominator_n = null_num*null_num;

for (i=0; i<M; i++)
{
    first_num = (a*null_num+c)%4294967296;
    numerator_n = numerator_n + null_num*first_num;
    numerator_2 = numerator_2 + first_num;
    denominator_n = denominator_n + first_num*first_num;
    null_num = first_num;
}

numerator_n = numerator_n + null_num*((a*x+c)%4294967296);
numerator_2 = numerator_2 + null_num;
denominator_2 = numerator_2;
denominator_n = denominator_n + null_num*null_num; 
C = (double)((numerator_n*M)-(numerator_2*numerator_2))/(double)((denominator_n*M)-(denominator_2*denominator_2));

printf("Coefficient: %f \n\n", C);
```

Comment: язык какой?

откуда 4294967296?

Comment: 4294967296 - 2^32 четыре байта, 2^(8*sizeof(int))

Comment: а в формуле он откуда?

Comment: это только автору ведомо, в формуле никаких делений с остатком нет, думаю защита от переполнения какая-то но я не сишник

Comment: @777Julia777 значения и типы a,x,c предоставте

Comment: @eicto: это видимо и правда приведение к 4-ём байтам. Судя по всему, `null_num` и `first_num` -- текущие члены последовательностей `U_i` и `V_i`. Только непонятно, почему об этом должны догадываться мы, а не узнать это от ТС.

Comment: В Си для **`unsigned int`** операцию *%4294967296* можно просто выбросить, **`unsigned int`** это (всюду где мне известно) 32 бита. 

Поэтому на это "урезание" до 32 бит можно внимания не обращать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш тест неверно реализован.

Делайте что-то такое:

```
double sumUV = 0, sumU = 0, sumV = 0, sumU2 = 0, sum V2 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    double u = GetNextU(i);
    double v = GetNextV(i);

    sumU += u; sumV += v;
    sumU2 += u*u; sumV2 += v*v;
    sumUV += u*v;
}
double coeff = (n * sumUV - sumU * sumV) /
          sqrt((n * sumU2 - sumU * sumU) * (n * sumV2 - sumV * sumV));
```

Это, к сожалению, достаточно наивный код: из-за неточности при округлении результат может оказаться катастрофически неточен. О подробностях читайте в Кнуте, 4.2.2. Пример после формулы (15) показывает, что при вычислении корня в знаменателе вы можете столкнуться с отрицательным числом, несмотря на то, что это математически невозможно.

---

Апдейт. С новой формулой у вас `V_i = U_{i+1}`, вы считаете корреляцию последовательности на себя. Код можно упростить.

```
double sumU = 0, sumU2 = 0, sumUShifted = 0;
double firstU = GetNextU(0);
double prevU = firstU;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    double nextU = i == (n - 1) ? firstU : GetNextU(i + 1);

    sumU += prevU;
    sumU2 += prevU*prevU;
    sumUShifted += prevU*nextU;

    prevU = nextU;
}
double coeff = (n * sumUShifted - sumU * sumU) / (n * sumU2 - sumU * sumU);
```

Comment: ну от и ни каких 4294967296

Comment: @GedWeb: 4294967296 уходит в реализацию `GetNextU`, но там, четно говоря, можно и без неё.

Comment: @VladD, а какой тут смысл в auto? Все равно ведь все дальше в double считается. 

Можно потребовать, чтобы GetNextU() возвращала double. Но, IMHO это не спасет ТС от потери/переполнения при N=50.

Недаром приличная часть второго тома отводится вычислениям в рациональных числах.

Comment: @avp: вы правы, сейчас почищу. У ТС они были целыми, но если завести переменную как double, будет правильнее.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, сейчас пойду разбираться! Ваш код у меня работает))
P.S. Извините, что не отвечала на вопросы, не было доступа к компьютеру.

Comment: @777Julia777: отлично, удачи вам! Но всё же берегитесь накопления неточностей.

Comment: Как раз сейчас этим занимаюсь..)
Спасибо, и Вам удачи!